# "Discrete word" meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I wonder what does the phrase "discrete word" mean. 
I came across this phrase in a context which someone wants advice someone else in a polite way, and the sentence is:

> I will have a discrete word.

Probably the speaker means  "I will have a discrete word with them"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel compelled to correct my spelling after StoneyB's answer. The correct spelling is *discreet*, not *discrete*.

**Discreet** here means *using discretion*, respecting issues of privacy and decency.

Having a word with someone means having a talk with them.

Having a *discreet* word with someone usually means you talk to someone in private - you take them apart at the coffee corner, or you move into a meeting room. It indicates the *opposite* of giving someone a public telling off.
It is often considered unkind to criticize someone in public, in front of their friends or colleagues. Having a *discreet* word with them, you make sure they do get the message,but it is not a public event.

Answer (score 4):

This is an error for *discreet*, which means

> Careful and prudent in one’s speech or actions, especially in order to keep something confidential or to avoid embarrassment. —[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discreet)

To *have a discreet word* with someone is to have a confidential, private conversation with them.

*Discrete* is quite different; it means “individually separate and distinct” ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discrete?q=discrete)). For instance

> Be careful you do not confuse the preposition *into*, compounded, with the collocation *in to*, composed of two discrete words.

The error is quite common even among native speakers, not only because the spellings are so similar but because the noun derivative of *discreet* is *discretion*.

> 

Comment: I had not even _seen_ the difference, but I managed to spell it correctly _once_ in my answer.

Comment: @oerkelens Many people never achieve that. :)

Comment: Actually I quoted the sentence without any change, and the person who wrote that is a native speaker. 
I googled the phrase and did not get a reasonable meaning, probably the misspelling was one of the reasons of my confusions.